# How can I make images in cells fill the entire height of an HTML email?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I've got a problem with an HTML email in that if the content is is increased the images that make up the left and right hand side are too short so it leaves a gap. I don't want to just make the images longer as this could leave  lot of whitespace depending on content.
I had the idea of using the same image twice with one set to `valign=top` and the other set to `valign=bottom`. I soon discovered it just stacks them one above the other though.
Is it possible to make them effectively slide over each other so that the appearance is that the image grows as the content increases?

The specific table cell code is as follows:

```
<td width=162 valign=top style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
<img src="email/images/left-bar.jpg" name="left bar top"
 width=102 border=0  id="leftbartop"
 valign=bottom style='padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm'>
<img src="email/images/left-bar.jpg" name="left bar bottom"
width=102 border=0  id="leftbarbottom"></td>
```

I have done some searching using a well known search engine and have only come across css functions for achieving this. I'm trying to steer clear of css and background images as outlook seems to be rather stubborn when it comes to displaying things involving background images.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use an image with a background image as css `position` or `z-index` are not well supported. Set a background image to the top of your cell. You would then use `valign="bottom"` in your table cell to align the standard image tag bottom image.

See [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm) for backgrounds that work in Outlook.